# shade the segment of a circle

Tags: tikz-pgf, circles

[image: circle]

How do I shade the segment AB in the above diagram so that I have the following?
[image]

This is the latex code I have so far.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newtheorem{theorem}{THEOREM}
\newtheorem{proof}{PROOF}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usepackage{fancyheadings}
\usepackage{bigints}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{stackengine,graphicx,xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs,array}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\begin{document}
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
%\pagecolor{blue!13}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[C]{\thepage}
\voffset = 0.1cm
\pagestyle{fancy}
\definecolor{Elite}{RGB}{37,97,172}
\definecolor{web}{RGB}{56, 102, 166}
\setlength{\parindent}{0mm}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\begin{tikzpicture}
%
\draw [thick] (0,0) circle (2.5);
%
%\node[above] at (1.97,1.77) {A};
%\node[below] at (1.97,-1.77) {B};
%
\draw [fill=black] (0,0) circle (0.05);
\node[left] at (0,0) {O};
%
\draw[thick] (0,0) --+ (1.768,1.768);
\draw[thick] (0,0) --+ (1.768,-1.768);
%
\node[right] at (0.2,0) {$45^{\circ}$};
\draw[thick] (1.768,1.768)--+ (0,-3.536);
%
\node[above] at (0.3,0.9) {$2.5$ cm};
\node[below] at (0.3,-0.9) {$2.5$ cm};
%
\node[above] at (1.868,1.868) {$A$};
\node[below] at (1.868,-1.868) {$B$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A common method for this is clipping the area and using \fill command after clipping:

PS: I used calc library for the calculation of the position (2.5\sqrt{2}/2)

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newtheorem{theorem}{THEOREM}
\newtheorem{proof}{PROOF}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usepackage{fancyheadings}
\usepackage{bigints}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{stackengine,graphicx,xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs,array}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, positioning,calc} %ADDED calc LIBRARY
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\begin{document}
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
%\pagecolor{blue!13}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[C]{\thepage}
\voffset = 0.1cm
\pagestyle{fancy}
\definecolor{Elite}{RGB}{37,97,172}
\definecolor{web}{RGB}{56, 102, 166}
\setlength{\parindent}{0mm}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\begin{tikzpicture}
%
  \draw [thick] (0,0) circle (2.5);
  \begin{scope}   %THESE 3 LINES WILL DO THE TRICK:
  \clip ({1.25*sqrt(2)},-2.5) rectangle (2.5,2.5);
  \fill[yellow] (0,0) circle (2.5);
  \end{scope}
  %
%\node[above] at (1.97,1.77) {A};
%\node[below] at (1.97,-1.77) {B};
%
\draw [fill=black] (0,0) circle (0.05);
\node[left] at (0,0) {O};
%
\draw[thick] (0,0) --+ (1.768,1.768);
\draw[thick] (0,0) --+ (1.768,-1.768);
%
\node[right] at (0.2,0) {$45^{\circ}$};
\draw[thick] (1.768,1.768)--+ (0,-3.536);
%
\node[above] at (0.3,0.9) {$2.5$ cm};
\node[below] at (0.3,-0.9) {$2.5$ cm};
%
\node[above] at (1.868,1.868) {$A$};
\node[below] at (1.868,-1.868) {$B$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Welcome... I think you can use intersections too, but I used the method I supposed is simpler... If you are interested on alternative ways I can add one.

Comment: May be I'll stick with the clip method for now. But it was really helpful. Thank you!

Comment: Ok... happy TeXing!

Comment: May be if you draw the circle after the scope of the fill we did, the result will be better... Try it!

Comment: This has nothing to do with your question, but I wanted to point out the existence of polar coordinates in TikZ: Use `(45:2.5)` instead of `(1.768,1.768)` and `(-45:2.5)` instead of `(1.768,-1.768)`. (Polar coordinates in TikZ are a bit weird, having the angle first and radius last. But you'll get used to it.)

Answer (score 5):

Just for completeness, without clip, intersections and packages that are not essential for this example.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
%
\draw [thick] (0,0) circle (2.5);
%
%\node[above] at (1.97,1.77) {A};
%\node[below] at (1.97,-1.77) {B};
%
\draw [fill=black] (0,0) circle (0.05);
\node[left] at (0,0) {O};
%
\draw[thick] (0,0) --+ (1.768,1.768);
\draw[thick] (0,0) --+ (1.768,-1.768);
%
\node[right] at (0.2,0) {$45^{\circ}$};
\draw[thick] (1.768,1.768)--+ (0,-3.536);
%
\node[above] at (0.3,0.9) {$2.5$ cm};
\node[below] at (0.3,-0.9) {$2.5$ cm};
%
\node[above] at (1.868,1.868) {$A$};
\node[below] at (1.868,-1.868) {$B$};
\draw[-,fill=yellow] (1.768,1.768) arc [start angle=45,end angle=-45,radius=2.5]
-- cycle;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I would say "not necessary" or "not really needed" or something similar instead of "not relevant". +1 (As it is better to avoid packages if not have to), also -1 because your method solves smaller amount of problems  ... :P (joking... only +1)

Comment: Also +1 to you ;-). I put essential now. The only point was that the minimal working example was not too minimal. I stripped off the not-so-essential packages since some people (and marmots;-) tend to use examples from TeX.SE, and try to learn which package is used for what purpose. And here they may think that, say, `\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}` is essential, which it is actually not.

Comment: You are right... Better practice than mine... Many times I just doesn't touch the code of the OP but only adding something if I have to or I have to suggest... Your way is better for the most of the users that will find the question... My way was more specific (because of possible conflicts etc on the real and not the MWE)... I will try to use your way more often...

Comment: @koleygr I also forget very often to strip off the not-so-essential packages.

Answer (score 3):

Another solution using a circular node. This way we can use `angular` anchors and there's no need for `intersections` library and previously calculated coordinate values.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm,tikz]{standalone}
%\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
%
\node[circle, minimum size=5cm, draw, thick, label=45:$A$, label=-45:$B$] (c) {};

\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\fill[yellow] (c.45) arc[start angle=45, end angle=-45, radius=2.5cm]--cycle;
\end{scope}

\draw[fill] circle(1pt) node[left]{$O$} node[right]{\SI{45}{\degree}};

\draw[thick, line join=bevel] (c.center)--node[above left]{\SI{2.5}{\cm}} ([shift={(-135:.5\pgflinewidth)}]c.45)--([shift={(135:.5\pgflinewidth)}]c.-45)-- node[below left]{\SI{2.5}{\cm}} cycle;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Forgive yet another solution, but here just for comparison is the same diagram in [Metapost](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html) -- this is wrapped up in [luamplib](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/luamplib?lang=en), so compile with `lualatex` or workout how to adapt it for plain MP, or the [GMP](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/gmp?lang=en) package.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib, luatex85}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);

    path C; C = fullcircle scaled 5cm;
    numeric a; a = 45;

    pair A, B;
    A = point  a * 8/360 of C;
    B = point -a * 8/360 of C;

    fill subpath (-a,a) * 8/360 of C -- cycle withcolor red + 3/4 green;

    draw origin -- B -- A -- cycle;
    draw C;

    dotlabel.lft("$O$", origin);
    dotlabel.urt("$A$", A);
    dotlabel.lrt("$B$", B);

    numeric r; 
    r = abs point 0 of C / cm;
    label.ulft(decimal r & "\thinspace cm", 1/2 A);
    label.llft(decimal r & "\thinspace cm", 1/2 B);

    draw subpath(-a,a) * 8/360 of fullcircle scaled 14;
    label("$" & decimal 2a & "^\circ$", 16 right);

endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

The main amusement here is that I've tried to make the labels automatic, so you can change the values of the diameter of the circle and the angle of A, and have the labels adjusted accordingly.

Note that MP defines a `fullcircle` path to have 8 "points", numbered 0 to 7 starting at 3 o'clock, so you can transform angles to points by multiplying by `8/360`.

Comment: Automatic labeling is an interesting idea! However, I do think that polar coordinates are more transparent that `point angle * 8/360`

Comment: @Aditya to be sure polar coordinates would be more elegant, but I was pleased to discover that I could multiply the pair `(a,-a)` directly so that `subpath` works neatly.   It would perhaps have been better to define the angle as `a = 45 * 8 / 360` but then my automatic label would not work so well.   I was just exploring the possibles really rather than trying to be "canonical".