# Fill area of circle delimited by a segment

Tags: tikz-pgf, circles

I want to fill the area delimited by the horizontal line and the bottom part of the circle blue. I followed the answers given in this post [shade the segment of a circle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/411363/shade-the-segment-of-a-circle) but somehow my code fills exactly the complement of the circle.
Here is my MWE

```
\documentclass[hidelinks,12pt,twoside,a4paper,reqno]{amsbook}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!h]
            \centering
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \coordinate (C) at (0,0);
                \coordinate (A) at (200:pi);
                \coordinate (B) at (-20:pi);
                \fill[blue!40] (A) arc[start angle=200, end angle=-20, radius=pi] -- cycle;
                \draw (C) -- (A);
                \draw (C) -- (B);
                \draw (A) -- (B);
                \draw (0,0) node[circle,draw,inner sep=1pt](C) {} circle (pi);
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Can please somebody tell me what I am missing? If I understood correctly, changing the start and end angle of the arc command should give the result but that just messes it up completely.

Comment: Use `end angle=340` or `delta angle=140` instead of `end angle=-20`?

Comment: `-20` is less then `200` so TikZ calculatess are clockwise arc. If you don't want to do math, use `end angle=-20+360`.

Comment: why do you need `inner sep=1pt` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[hidelinks,12pt,twoside,a4paper,reqno]{amsbook}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!h]
            \centering
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \coordinate (C) at (0,0);
                \coordinate (A) at (200:pi);
                \coordinate (B) at (-20:pi);
                \fill[blue!40] (A) arc[start angle=200, end angle=340, radius=pi];
                \draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle;
                \draw (0,0) node[circle,draw,inner sep=1pt]{} (C) circle (pi);
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

With a `path picture` you can draw whatever you want inside a `path` and the result is clipped by the path. In this case, a rectangle large enough is clipped by the lower part of the circle.

```
\documentclass[hidelinks,12pt,twoside,a4paper,reqno]{amsbook}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!h]
            \centering
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \coordinate (C) at (0,0);
                \coordinate (A) at (200:pi);
                \coordinate (B) at (-20:pi);
                \draw (C) -- (A); 
                \draw (C) -- (B);
                \draw (A) -- (B);
                \draw[path picture={ \draw[fill=blue!30] (200:pi) rectangle ++(7,-3);}] (0,0)   
                        node[circle,draw,inner sep=1pt](C) {} circle (pi);
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]